# (UITableView) Background pattern image issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, background-image

There are two pieces of code:

code 1:

```
UIView* _backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] frame]] autorelease];
[_backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testbg"]]];
[[self tableViewCountrySelector] setBackgroundView:_backView];
```

code 2:

```
UIView* _backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] frame]] autorelease];
[[self tableViewCountrySelector] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testbg"]]];
[[self tableViewCountrySelector] setBackgroundView:_backView];
```

My question is:

1. Why the above codes are outputting the same result? The codes are supposed to resolve pattern image issues for the background of UITableView.

I just don't understand how's code 2 works.